# Why does the compilation pass with no warnings/errors?

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, x86

```
#include <stdio.h>
union {
    struct {
        int a;
        int c;
    };
    struct {
        int b;
        int a;
    };
}unionTry;

int main(){
    unionTry.a = 1;
    unionTry.b = 2;
    unionTry.c = 3;


    printf("a = 0x%x b = 0x%x c = 0x%x\n", unionTry.a, unionTry.b, unionTry.c); 
    return 0;
}
```

The disassembly:

```
  400578:   55                      push   %rbp
  400579:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
  40057c:   c7 05 56 04 20 00 01    movl   $0x1,0x200456(%rip)        # 6009dc <unionTry>
  400583:   00 00 00 
  400586:   c7 05 50 04 20 00 02    movl   $0x2,0x200450(%rip)        # 6009e0 <unionTry+0x4>
  40058d:   00 00 00 
  400590:   c7 05 46 04 20 00 03    movl   $0x3,0x200446(%rip)        # 6009e0 <unionTry+0x4>
  400597:   00 00 00 
  40059a:   8b 0d 40 04 20 00       mov    0x200440(%rip),%ecx        # 6009e0 <unionTry+0x4>
  4005a0:   8b 15 3a 04 20 00       mov    0x20043a(%rip),%edx        # 6009e0 <unionTry+0x4>
  4005a6:   8b 35 30 04 20 00       mov    0x200430(%rip),%esi        # 6009dc <unionTry>
  4005ac:   bf bc 06 40 00          mov    $0x4006bc,%edi
  4005b1:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
  4005b6:   e8 e5 fe ff ff          callq  4004a0 <printf@plt>
  4005bb:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
  4005c0:   c9                      leaveq 
  4005c1:   c3                      retq   
  4005c2:   90                      nop
```

The output:

```
$gcc -Wall a.c && ./a.out
a = 0x2 b = 0x2 c = 0x3
```

Apparently it is a lack of C11 standard support. Is the following code is well defined:

```
union {
    struct {
        int a;
        int c;
    };
    struct {
        int a;
        int b;
    };
}unionTry;
```

Comment: If compiled, nice q, +1. Loking forward for answer. Maybe compiler optimization to unnamed structs, let's see.

Comment: Doesn't compile for me. Which Gcc version is this?

Comment: @mafso I do have quite old compiler version on my VM :

`>gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 4.1.2
Copyright (C) 2006 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
`
What error do you get?

Comment: @mafso, [here](http://codepad.org/BRv97pEo) its behavior or unexpected behavior with another compiler version

Comment: @0x90 I suppose anonymous struct/union had not yet been added to gcc in that old version. There were formally added to the C language in 2012, with the C11 standard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anonymous structures and unions have been standardized in C11. Gcc allowed them before as an extension. For both versions, the structure or union declaration must be unambiguous (`a` in this code example is ambiguous and thus violates this rule). In C11, such violations must be detected at compile time, and new versions of Gcc follow this requirement also when compiling with a GNU dialect.

With Gcc 4.1.2, it isn't detected. From the [docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/gcc/Unnamed-Fields.html#Unnamed-Fields) [emph. mine]:

> You must never create such structures that cause ambiguous field definitions. For example, this structure:
>
> ```
> struct {
>     int a;
>     struct {
>         int a;
>     };
> } foo;
> ```
>
> It is ambiguous which `a` is being referred to with `foo.a`. Such constructs are not supported and must be avoided. *In the future, such constructs may be detected and treated as compilation errors*.

The emphasized entry has been changed for version [4.6.4](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.4/gcc/Unnamed-Fields.html#Unnamed-Fields).

Answer (score 2):

It does not compile.

With MinGW, gcc 4.9.1 and your compiler settings:

```
gcc -Wall test.c
test.c:9:13: error: duplicate member 'a'
         int a;
             ^
```

With proper compiler settings:

```
gcc test.c -std=c11 -pedantic-errors -Wall -Wextra
test.c:9:13: error: duplicate member 'a'
         int a;
             ^
```

Update your version of gcc. Anonymous struct/union was added in C11 (but existed as a gcc extension before that).